# R: counting frequency to use in levelplot

Tags: r

I have point series in a data.frame with duplication. I would like to plot them using level plot, and use as a Z frequency of x, y (in example how many times for x = 1 there was y = 2). How can I do this? Well it is easy for me to explain myself with SQL syntax:

```
 SELECT x, y, count(*) from data_frame GROUP BY x, y
```

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of summarizing a data frame by groups defined by variables is very common in R. Many of the *pply functions would work. The standard response these days is to use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
ddply(data_frame,.(x,y),summarise,total = NROW(piece))
```

In general, you should really learn the `plyr` package, along with all the base `*pply` functions.

But if you're more comfortable with SQL, you might consider looking at the `sqldf` package, which lets you do a lot of these kinds of manipulations of data frames directly with SQL.

Comment: thanks! sqldf looks interesting, however I will give a try to plyr package

Answer (score 1):

I don't doubt that many people get good results with plyr functions, but this is really a question that is easily answered with one of `tapply`,  `table`, or `ave` depending upon the unstated needs for this result. Both `tapply` and `table` would yield contingency tables which are really matrices or arrays and therefore very easy to access.

```
with( data_frame, table( x , y ) )
```

Comment: is it easy to use the resul in levelplot() ?

Comment: @mkk. I'm certainly willing to try, but would need more specifics. `levelplot` is just regular R and Sarkar makes a concerted effort to make his code "regular".

Comment: thanks! I will try your approach once I go back to this, since the previous solution works pefectly but not on my large data set - 5 minutes was not enough to generate new data frame, I hope your solution scales better :)